# Converting SQL query to JPA NamedQuery

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, named-query

I'm trying to implement a Keyword search functionality that returns a List of Keyword entities based on a field text match.

Right now, the query

```
select * from photo_keywords pk
inner join keywords k on pk.photo_id = k.keyword_id
inner join photos p on pk.keyword_id = p.photo_id
where k.keyword LIKE "%$SOME_SEARCH_VALUE%";
```

returns all matching photos for a given keyword search.  I'd like to have this adapted to a `@NamedQuery` with the following Entity objects:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "keywords")
public class Keyword implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "keyword_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String keyword;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "keywords")
    private List<Photo> photos;

    //getters and setters
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "photos")
public class Photo implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "photo_id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "photo_name", nullable = false)
    private String photoName;

    @Column(name = "photo_path", nullable = false)
    private String photoPath;

    @Column(name = "upload_date", nullable = false)
    private Date uploadDate;

    @Column(name = "view_count", nullable = false)
    private int viewCount;

    @Column(name = "capture_date", nullable = false)
    private Date captureDate;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "photo_metadata")
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "metadata_name")
    @Column(name = "metadata_value")
    private Map<String, String> photoMetadata;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "photo_keywords",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "keyword_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "photo_id"))
    public List<Keyword> keywords;

    //getters and setters

}
```

This creates a join table `photo_keywords`, rather than a JoinColumn.

What I've tried so far with the `Keyword` entity:

```
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(
            name = "findKeywordByName",
            query = "SELECT keyword from Keyword k WHERE k.keyword = :keyword"
    )
})
```

which is executed via

```
public Keyword findKeywordByString(String keyword){
    Keyword thisKeyword;
    Query queryKeywordExistsByName = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("findKeywordByName");
    queryKeywordExistsByName.setParameter("keyword", keyword);

    try {

        thisKeyword = new Keyword((String) queryKeywordExistsByName.getSingleResult());

    } catch (NoResultException e){
        thisKeyword = null;
    }

    return thisKeyword;
}
```

This returns the Keyword, but with the `photos` property being null.  This is to be expected, since I'm only selecting the `keyword` property.  How can I adapt the SQL query above to a `@NamedQuery`?

Comment: Do you have a property with the same name of the class? While not incorrect (in the sense of compilation error), it will lead to mistakes and is a smell of bad design. That said, `SELECT k from Keyword k ...` will return the entity, check about fetching to learn more about loading properties. Ah, and the question is too broad.

Comment: ack.. yes.  I can refactor it to `photoList` instead.